# Drawing text, newline character, Quartz 2D

Tags: iphone, quartz-graphics

I was trying to draw a text in Quartz.  For example:

```
20.0%
1/5
```

I thought I could do something like this:

```
NSString *label = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.1f%%\n1/5",someValue * 100];
```

However the newline gets drawn as a box.  Is there a way around this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Split up the string into separate text elements, each on their own line.